# Is there any way to attach multiple roles to single policy?

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create iam roles in terraform, in which 2-3 policies are common, So is there any way i can attach those roles to policy?

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "alerts-config-params-sam-cf-accessToKmsKeyIAMPolicy-CZV903G9AVJR" {
  role       = ["${module.role1.name}","${module.role2.name}","${module.role3.name}",]
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::policy"
}
```

This is the policy in which i am trying to attach 3 roles

```
"${module.role1.name}","${module.role2.name}","${module.role3.name}",
```

The exact error is:

```
aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole: role must be a single value, not a list
```

and if i create this policy multiple time attaching single role to it, it gives error like:

```
aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole: resource repeated multiple times
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `aws_iam_role_policy_attachment` resource, you will need to create a separate attachment for each role. Make sure you give them different names.

Alternatively, you may consider using `iam_policy_attachment`, which accepts a list of roles. Make sure you read and understand the warning at the top of the page though.